# Preference to one match in Regex when overlapping matches exist?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression that matches *x* OR *y* condition.  Sometimes those matches overlap and I want to give preference to one of the conditions.

Here is my test case.

Regex:

```
X[^\w]*\>|\>[^\w]*X
```

Input:

> Soup > X > Alphabet
>   Alphabet Soup > X
>   X > Alphabet Soup

Matches:

> [Highlighted match results http://i.friendfeed.com/b55db94551503bf13d16f944fc56d9ff56676b4f](http://i.friendfeed.com/b55db94551503bf13d16f944fc56d9ff56676b4f)

The first highlighted match (yellow) should be **X >** instead of **> X** but I'm not sure how to give preference to one of the matches given an overlap.

Comment: So you want to match "X >" unless it's at the end of the line (in which case you want to match "> X")?

Comment: no, I want to match "X >" anytime it exists and "> X" anytime it exists and the "X >" does not.  This example is really about the first line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
X[^\w]*>|>[^\w]*X(?![^\w]*>)
```

A negative look-ahead after the low-prioritized alternative. When it finds `"> X"`, but there is a `" >"` after it, it should be skipped in favor of `"X >"`.